# Modulo alternatives for Java

Tags: java, modulo

I currently have this statement

`b = (b + 1) % a.length;`

However my prof isn't fond of modulo for this assignment.
I was wondering how I would be able to rewrite this to make it work without a modulo..

Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Can you include the rest of the code for context?

Comment: Your prof's personal preferences aside, that use of modulo is widely accepted and understood by programmers everywhere.

Comment: Some of the surrounding code might make for a more pleasant solution.

Answer (score 2):

Try this, it has the same effect and avoids using modulo. IMHO, the modulo-based solution is preferred, it's a shame that your teacher doesn't like it:

```
// assuming that `b` is an integer
if (b + 1 >= a.length) {
    b = ((b+1) - ((b+1)/a.length * a.length));
} else {
    b++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If in the context of the question you are trying to make 'b' serve as a index into something of fixed length and you are supposed to increment 'b' until its at the length boundary at which point 'b' gets set back to 0.  You Modulo solution is exactly how you see this done "in the real world".

However, in "the real world" telling your prof he is a git rarely works out.

```
int b = 0;
...
while( !someExitCondition() ) {
  ...
  doSomething( a.get( b ) );
  if ( b + 1 < a.length ) {
    b++;
  } else {
    b = 0;
  }
}
```